# Images loose quality when using image.asset in flutter

Tags: image, dart, flutter

I have user Image.asset for a png, but have remarked that image loose quality;
how to preserve same quality in real devices?

Comment: no, png does not loose quality

Comment: but I see that text inside png looks not clear, not like TEXt widget

Comment: because it is scaled down (or up) - it cannot be done without any imperfections

Comment: You could try to change the size and quality of your png in for example Inkscape, Adobe or Photoshop (there are ofcourse more).

Comment: so what I need to do to solve this , I am talking first about flutter , for the size I have used two different size but I see same result,

Comment: I've same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58041586/why-transparent-images-look-poor-quality-in-flutter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my case, the problem was due to a bad configuration of the image resolution system.

On the one hand, you have to specify the different resolutions in the assets folder.

```
assets/my_icon.png
assets/2.0x/my_icon.png
assets/3.0x/my_icon.png
```

On the other hand, you have to declare these variants in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/2.0x/
    - assets/3.0x/
```

More information in the [Flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#resolution-aware).

*TIP: If you export the images from another program (Adobe XD for example), you can automate this task with the [image_res package](https://pub.dev/packages/image_res).*

Answer (score 0):

I mean It's a really common problem, the problem is with flutter and also the file size, the image is either too big and you are scaling it down or either it is too small and you are scaling it up, at the end it's an image and there will be loss of image quality, I had the same problem, my image size was too big, I used powerpoint, I mean don't laugh, I stretched down the image, and then saved it as an image, and then it was super sharp. Hope this helps, this powerpoint technique is quite useful, saves time lolz, fun way to use powerpoint too.