# Why Transparent Images Look Poor Quality in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, flutter, dart

I have png images that have drop shadow. There is no unproportional images scaling problem, scaling are according to the aspect ratio.

When I using `Image.asset()` for placing images on phone screen, they're and their shadows looks low quality and not soft.

Original image looks: http://prnt.sc/p93vo2

Image on Android App: https://prnt.sc/p93vz3

Example images are same and 700x400, 96dpi.
You should see quality difference between images.
There is also a strange stuation. The shadow density on right and bottom side is more than shadow of original image on android app.

I've tried `FilterQuality.high` but no change, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was due to a bad configuration of the image resolution system.

Full answer [SO: Images loose quality when using image.asset in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63952626/6322000)
.