# flutter web pictures get pixelated

Tags: image, flutter, dart, flutter-web

My normal quality images are pixelated, the picture is normally good quality

[this is my image in project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgX8c.png)

my basic code

```
Image.asset("url", filterQuality: FilterQuality.high),
```

Comment: I seem to have the same issue. Have you found a solution for this issue?

Answer (score -1):

The resolutions of your image are - 122 × 80.
If you are displaying it bigger than that will cause the picture to lose quality (Pixelate).

Comment: There should be no loss of quality when shrinking the big picture. how can ı fix it

Comment: refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63952626/14119330) you may find your answer here.Here is the official docs regarding image quality [Docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#resolution-aware)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but in some scenarios I have to extract data from the network. I still have the same problem.

Comment: I couldn't find any solution, not a solution but i used svg